# Not able to find executables by using rosrun

Tags: ros-fuerte, rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am following the tutorials and created the files named talker.cpp and listner.cpp according to tutorial 11 and also used rosedit to edit CMakeLists.txt.

But i am not able to find the executables in bin.

also $rosrun beginner_tutorials talker is not working.

the error is:
could not find executable named talker below /home/anand/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/beginner_tutorials

i have tried using rospack profile but was not useful.

I am new to ROS...please help as soon as possible.

I am using ros fuerte with rosbuild method in ubuntu 12.04 installed in virtualbox.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/114066/not-able-to-find-executables-by-using-rosrun/) by [Anand](https://answers.ros.org/users/10351/anand/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2013-12-31

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks a lot for replying.
The problem is solved now.
i forgot to put '}' at the end of talker.cpp due to which rosmake was giving failure error.

---

Originally posted by [Anand](https://answers.ros.org/users/10351/anand/) with karma: 26 on 2013-12-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you remembered to build your package? Ie:

```
$ rosmake PKG_NAME
```

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2013-12-31

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-12-31**:
Please accept this answer so others don't spend time trying to help you solve a solved problem.